# How to generate Full spectrum analysis in vibration using Python

Tags: signal-processing, fft, vibration, spectrum, orbit

[Mathematical procedure for obtaining a full spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pngUy.png)

[the spectrum obtained from the data from two probes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pjJP.png)

I need some help. I aquired vibration signals using Adre 408 & Pulse 3560C.

When using Adre 408, I just checked the full spectrum on test rig and To analyze the vibration signal, the vibration signal was acquired using Pulse 3560C. (Time series data cannot be saved using Adre).

I understand that Full spectrum used the amplitude & phase of positive and negative.

However, I have no idea how to perform signal processing to express the full spectrum.

Please help me

I tried using the real and image areas that occur after FFT processing, but this is not correct.
If this method requires using the Major axis and Minor axis generated from Orbit, please help.